# How to take mysql dump without primary key in terminal

Tags: mysql

I want to dump the values of a table except the primary key using shell command. Is there any possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use command line args after `mysql` to run query from command line. List all columns except primary key: `SELECT col1, col2, ...`.